# Kubernetes: add NGINX webserver

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, minikube

I managed to create and deploy a k8s cluster with minikube, running 4 replicas of a simple hello-world node.js app, using the following configuration.

Dockerfile for the app:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm
# TODO could uninstall some build dependencies

# debian installs `node` as `nodejs`
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10

COPY package.json package.json

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

k8s Deployment yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: node-deployment
  labels:
    app: node-app
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: node-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: node-app
        image: my-repo/ubuntu-node:sectry 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node-service
  labels:
    app: node-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: node-app
```

My question is how can add an nginx container for it? I know k8s cluster already load-balancing, but I really wish to use NGINX features.

Comment: Look at this [tutorial](http://sharepointoscar.com/2017-04-12-deploy-a-static-site-using-an-nginx-docker-container-to-a-local-kubernetes-minikube-instance/) to get it via dashboard. Deploying just NGINX not required deep dive into configuration of Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to use nginx as a reverse proxy to your Node.js app. If it is the case, you can use one of the following ways to achieve it.

**Option 1**

1. Build nginx and your node.js app into one Docker image. In this image, configure nginx as a reverse proxy and forward the request to your node.js app. For example, the following nginx configure forwards the request to port 3000 in the same container.

   ```
   server {
       listen      80;
       server_name localhost;

       location / {
           proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
           proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3000;
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can then deploy this image to k8s cluster, and create a service for it.

**Option 2**

1. Create 2 docker images: 1 for nginx and 1 for your node.js.
2. Deploy both of them to k8s and create a service for each of them. Use `ClusterIP` as the service type for node.js image, and `LoadBalancer` for nginx image.
3. Configure nginx as the reverse proxy, and forward the request to the corresponding cluster ip of the service for node.js image.

To test it on minikube, Option 1 is easier. Option 2 is recommended for a production k8s cluster.

Comment: Hi, It's better to use ingress-controller as a reverse proxy. You can check out the following example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507766/kubernetes-ingress-running-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy

Answer (score 2):

I would add third option : use an Ingress Controller https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress.

It will create all this features that you are looking for and built in on K8s.